# How to perform the computation of a new column for a dataframe with the calculation provided as a string (and avoiding eval())

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'1': [10, 20, 30], 2: [100, 200, 300]})

#    1    2
#0  10  100
#1  20  200
#2  30  300
```

The goal is to calculate a new column. However, the calculation is provided as a string:

```py
calc = '{1}+{2}'
```

**How can I calculate a new column based on the existing columns and the provided calculation?**

What I tried:

My initial idea was to use `apply` on the dataframe and `lambda` to make the calculation. Before that I would adjust the calculation string accordingly. However, that would make the use of `eval` necessary:

```py
for i in range(10):
    calc = calc.replace('{'+str(i)+'}', 'row["'+str(i)+'"]')
# outputs calc = 'row["1"]+row["2"]'

df['new_col'] = df.apply(lambda row: eval(calc), axis=1)
# basically:    df.apply(lambda row: eval('row["1"]+row["2"]'), axis=1)
```

Since I want to avoid `eval`, I am looking for a different solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use pandas' [`eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html) method, but you would need to remove the curly brackets and you cannot have numerical column names.

One option would be to adapt the string to add a prefix (e.g. `col`) using a regex:

```
calc = '{1}+{2}'
import re

query = re.sub('{([^}]+)}', r'col\1', calc)
# col1+col2

df['new_col'] = df.add_prefix('col').eval(query)
```

output:

```
    1    2  new_col
0  10  100      110
1  20  200      220
2  30  300      330
```